# How to print on endless paper on a CUPS printer using lp/lpr?

Tags: cups, printing, lp, lpr, brother

### The Situation

I'm trying to print on a [Brother QL-570](https://support.brother.com/g/b/producttop.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=lpql570eus) I set up on a Raspberry Pi using CUPS.
The printer is working well using `lp -d Brother_QL-570 test.pdf`. However, when I insert an endless label (a 30m long, 62mm wide label) I want it to print the exact length of the pdf file. For example, if the pdf provided has a format of 62x200, I want the printer to produce a 62mmx200mm long label.

If I use my Windows machine this works, but with lp, it doesn't.
`lpoptions -p Brother_QL-570 -l` yields the following: https://pastebin.com/yBJHw7a7. CUPS has [these settings](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1R5uMX46Qfb52yDMFanejrm6Em7EVoYKj/view?usp=sharing)
The printed label is always 62mmx100mm.

I did use `brpapertoollpr_ql570 -P Brother_QL-570 -n long_label -w 62 -h 200` in combination with `lpr -P Brother_QL-570 -o media=long_label test.pdf` to successfully to print 62mmx200mm labels, but creating a new media size for every new pdf I want to print would be quite tedious.

### Log files

Job 26 is from windows (working)
Job 27 is from lpr (too short)
[CUPS error_log](https://pastebin.com/SUdu1wDj)

printjob-data captured following [this guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingPrintingProblems#Capturing_print_job_data)
[job 26](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1QzVinBTBwCWMNlKKhnUvGbsAxOE3r6zc&usp=drive_fs)
[job 27](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1R3-h01fSj7GNT6JmyLrTI2gu2fK2iwHL/view?usp=sharing)